# Randomly select row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this query:

```
SELECT s.studentID,   s.studentName, s.projectTitle, s.lecturerID,
sv.lecturerID,sv.lecturerFullname AS supervisor,
ex.lecturerID,ex.lecturerfullname AS examiner,
f.availableID, f.lecturerID, f.freedate,
v.availableID, v.availableday, v.availablestart, v.availableend
FROM student s
INNER JOIN lecturer sv
ON s.lecturerID = sv.lecturerID
CROSS JOIN (free f
INNER JOIN lecturer ex
ON f.lecturerID = ex.lecturerID
INNER JOIN availability v
ON f.availableID = v.availableID)
WHERE f.lecturerID = ? 
AND s.lecturerID = ?
AND s.studentID = ?
AND f.freedate IS NOT NULL
```

This query is used to find `examiner` who his `freedate` IS NOT NULL and assign the date available.

Eg of `free` table:

```
freeid  lecturerID availableID   freedate
2451    1004           6        11-05-2016 
2461    1002           6        11-05-2016 
2471    1001           21       17-06-2016 
2481    1001           8        27-06-2016
```

Lecturer can be `examiner` or `supervisor`. In this query, it is specifically for `examiner`. Thus, assume `lecturerID` in `free` table is for `examiner`.

As you can see `lecturerID = 1001` has two `freedate`.
However, the problem is, the date inserted is always only `17-06-2016`.

I would like the query is more flexible where it will choose randomly `freedate` of a lecturer (examiner) if the one examiner has two or more `freedate`.

Each date can only be used four times only (if possible)..

Current outcome ( i removed unrelated column):

```
StudentID   StudentName     availableDay         freeDate
  2013         abc             Friday           17-06-2016
  2014         def             Friday           17-06-2016
  2015         ghi             Friday           17-06-2016
  2016         klm             Friday           17-06-2016
  2010         nop             Friday           17-06-2016
```

Expected outcome:

```
StudentID   StudentName     availableDay         freeDate
  2013         abc             Friday           17-06-2016
  2014         def             Monday           27-06-2016
  2015         ghi             Monday           27-06-2016
  2016         klm             Friday           17-06-2016
  2010         nop             Friday           17-06-2016
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are cross joining a Sub Query without a select statement or a table alias at the moment.

```
CROSS JOIN (free f
    INNER JOIN lecturer ex
    ON f.lecturerID = ex.lecturerID
    INNER JOIN availability v
    ON f.availableID = v.availableID)
```

Do you really want a `cross join`?  what is the edata structure of `free`? Are all of the dates you desire contained in the `free` table because that looks to be the source of the column in question. Would and `inner join` or a `left join` be more efficient for the free table?

Comment: I used `cross join` because the table is unrelated between `supervisor` and `examiner`. `ex.lecturerID` refers to examiner's ID

Comment: And yes, all dates are from `free` table. the column is `freedate`. I honestly do not know if there is any better solution. It would be nice, instead of making two queries, one for examiner and one for supervisor. I hope I can (too) modify this query to also look for supervisor who has `freedate` in the same query. I hope you understand hehe

Comment: Maybe I will come back to this and see if I can make better since of your joins but it looks like that part of your query needs some work.  As far as randomly choosing a row you have to tell the database engine what row to choose!  If you want it to be random you have to inject a random string or number that you can order your results and choose the first one by.  In this case generate a GUID sys_guid(), and then build a row_number partitioned by lecturerid and then choose where rownumber = 1.

Comment: Okay sure :) Thank you very much. Ill be waiting

Comment: @user6308605 @Matt To randomly select a row in a query, a trick is to add an `ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` statement and select first row returned using `WHERE ROWNUM=1`

Comment: @CarloCe glad to hear oracle has a random math function.  As one of my comments mentions you can also use a new GUID and a window function row_number() order on that to get the same affect.

Comment: Oh thank you. Do i have just at to my query. Or do i need to modify the query?